# How to change title using ng-idle title directive

Tags: angularjs, ng-idle

I'm trying to change the page title using ng-idle:

My title:

```
<title>MySite Local</title>
```

The code that doesn't seem to be working:

```
app.run(function (Title) {
    Title.idleMessage('You are idle');
});
```

Taken from https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle/issues/128

Am I missing anything here? The title doesn't change without the above code either.

I've also got `TitleProvider.enabled(true);` just in case.

Comment: looks like you need `Title.setEnabled(true)` just in case

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that directive, but if all you're trying to do is set the title, a plain old controller will work.

titleController.js
    (() => {
        "use strict"

```
        angular.module('myApp').controller('titleController', titleController)

        function titleController($scope) {
            $scope.appTitle = "Hi Dad, I'm in jail!"
        }

})()
```

index.html

{{appTitle}}

Of course, you'd have to add your own logic to detect an idle user.